# Creating a repository and uploading artifacts to a Nexus3 docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, sonatype, nexus3

This is basically a two part question.

First I would like to know how I would go about creating a new repository on a Nexus3 container after the container starts up. I know the rough outline on what has to be done, I just dont know how to do it.
Basically, two cURL requests have to be sent to the container AFTER it is ready. The  cURL requests are as follows:

```
curl -X POST -u admin:admin123 --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
http://127.0.0.1:8081/service/rest/v1/script \
-d '{"name":"newrepo","type":"groovy","content":"repository.createMavenHosted('\''new-repo'\'');"}'

curl -X POST -u admin:admin123 --header "Content-Type: text/plain" 'http://127.0.0.1:8081/service/rest/v1/script/newrepo/run'
```

(The above curl requests work when I manually send them via an app like Postman AFTER the container is ready. I am just unsure on how to make docker do it for me)

Secondly, I would like to know how to move artifacts to the newly created repository. Is there a location on the nexus3 image where I can just execute a `COPY` command and just copy the required artifacts to the repository?

Below is part of my `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: "2.1"
services: 
    nexus:
        container_name: nexus-container
        image: sonatype/nexus3
        ports:
            - "8081:8081"
```

This is just part of the entire file as the entire file a bit bigger therefore I did not want to post the entire thing, but I can do so if needed.

Thanks for any assistance provided :)

Comment: It is unclear what you want to achieve. Why can't you create the repo after the container is up? (e.g. via the UI)

Comment: The requirement is such that the repository should be created once the container starts up

Comment: Is it not possible to achieve the requirements? @Henry

Answer (score 0):

The work directory should be on persistent storage, so you shouldn't need to recreate configuration on every startup.

https://github.com/sonatype/docker-nexus3#persistent-data

That said, if you really do need to do this it can be done via the scripting/provisioning API's:

https://github.com/sonatype/docker-nexus3#persistent-data